# Increase the marker size of SOME of the markers in a seaborn pairplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm trying to change the size of only SOME of the markers in a seaborn pairplot.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'num_legs': [2, 4, 8, 0],
                   'num_wings': [2, 0, 0, 0],
                   'num_specimen_seen': [10, 2, 1, 8]},
                  index=['falcon', 'dog', 'spider', 'fish'])
```

Prettier:

```
        num_legs  num_wings  num_specimen_seen  class
falcon         2          2                 10      1
dog            4          0                  2      2
spider         8          0                  1      3
fish           0          0                  8      4
```

I want to for example increase the size of all samples with class=4.
How could this be done with the seaborn pairplot?

What I have so far:

```
sns.pairplot(data=df,diag_kind='hist',hue='class')
```

[image]

I have tried adding `plot_kws={"s": 3}`, but that changes the size of all the dots. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After checking out how the `pairplot` is built up, one could iterate through the axes and change the size of each 4th set of scatter dots:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

N = 100
classes = np.random.randint(1, 5, N)
df = pd.DataFrame({'num_legs': 2 * classes  % 8,
                   'num_wings': (classes == 1) * 2,
                   'num_specimen_seen': np.random.randint(1,20,N),
                   'class': classes})
g = sns.pairplot(data=df,diag_kind='hist',hue='class')

for ax in np.ravel(g.axes):
    if len(ax.collections) == 4:
        ax.collections[3].set_sizes([100])
g.fig.legends[0].legendHandles[3].set_sizes([100])

plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]